# How do I load my own function with 'tabBarOnPress'?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to load my imagePicker() function each time a particular tab is selected. Right now im trying to hijack onTabFocus, but its not working. Is there any other way that i can achieve this?

```
    export class AddImage extends Component{

    imagePicker(){
            //definition of function.......
    }

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
     return {
         tabBarOnPress({jumpToIndex, scene}) {
              navigation.state.params.onTabFocus();
         }
     }
    }
     componentDidMount(){
        this.props.navigation.setParams({onTabFocus: this.imagePicker.bind(this)})
    }
   }

   export default createBottomTabNavigator({
         Home: { screen: Home, 
          navigationOptions:{
              tabBarLabel: 'Home',
              tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>(<Icon name="home" color={tintColor} size={24}/>)
          }
        },
    AddImage: { screen: AddImage
      navigationOptions:{
       tabBarLabel: '',
       tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>(<Icon name="plus-square" color={tintColor} size={24}/>),
       tabBarOnPress: ({navigation})=> {navigaition.state.params.onTabFocus() },
       }
     },
        Settings: { screen: Settings,
          navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>(<Icon name="cog" color={tintColor} size={24}/>)
          }  
         },
    },

    {//other bottom tab configurations
      order: ['Home', 'AddImage', 'Settings'],
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need onTabFocus event. you can use [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html)

Here is working snack. you can check `Tab2.js` and console.log

https://snack.expo.io/@nazrdogan/moody-donuts

Comment: Not quite what i was after. I dont need to render anything (but a black screen). The main thing im trying to achieve, is that everytime a user clicks on the 'AddImage' tab, my function is executed that allows them to go to the iOS gallery and pick an image. I just don't know how to do this..

Comment: ok. you can do with this. Please check snack again. I updated example.

Comment: I will certainly give this a try. I'm currently using react-navigation v1.1.147 (as it seems relatively stable with my current RN version). May i ask which version of react-navigation you are using to enable NavigationEvents?

Comment: "react-navigation": "3.0.9"